# What is a class file? What is in that file?

Tags: java

I know this probably won't matter to most beginners who just want to write app and that they will probably know it as they do more in Java, but it's been six months learning Java, I have no idea what this is which is the very first chapter of my Java book. So I guess I should ask.

From what I read on the book, a file class contains source code which compiler translate using resources from Java library. And it can only be created when all syntax error is fixed.

So is it just a normal file we store in our computer with a .java ending?

And also where is Java library? And how big is it?

Comment: A class is a `.class` file that is a compiled `.java` file. The top level `class` in a `.java` file must share a name with the file. The Java library is wherever you installed it and I'm sure Explorer/Finder/Dolphin will happily tell you the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using java, you will encounter a few different types of files:

- .java file:  These are the text files where source code lives.  Those .java files are compiled to .class files.
- .class file:  This is byte code compiled by the javac program.  The javac program creates these files from .java files.  The java classloader loads classes from these files and not from the .java files.
- .jar file:  This is what you're referring to as a java library.  It is a collection of .class files, .properties files, and other files.  It's just a zip file with the extension changed to .jar
- .war file:  This is a web application archive.  It's very similar to a .jar file.  It contains classes in /WEB-INF/classes and jars in /WEB-INF/LIB
- .ear file:  This is a way to package multiple wars into one file.
- .properties file:  java.util.Properties can be read easily from these.  It's a text file, with each line in the format of key=value.

Comment: I think I should delete this question . Sorry